# Convert D3DXVECTOR3 to D3DXVECTOR4

Tags: c++, dll, vector, implicit-conversion, direct3d

i've run into a problem.. where I need to convert a D3DXVECTOR3 var into a D3DXVECTOR4 variable.

I've been trying to find an example on how to do this, but with no success.

```
D3DXVECTOR3 lPos, vHead;
D3DXVECTOR4 vDiff = vHead - lPos;
```

Comment: D3DXmath is ancient. Take a look at [DirectXMath](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/03/27/introducing-directxmath.aspx) or the [SimpleMath](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SimpleMath) wrapper for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this to initialize from a 3 component vector to 4.

```
D3DXVECTOR4 vDiff(vHead - lPos, 0.0f);
```

*Note depending on how vDiff is used, you may want to initialize the fourth component with a 1 instead?*